# How to disable certain dates in the Android Date Picker dialog?

Tags: android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I am using default Android `DatePickerDialog` which contains `android.widget.DatePicker`.

Does anybody know how to disable or make certain dates unselectable?

I know `DatePicker` allows to `setMinDate()` and `setMaxDate()` but it doesn't allow to disable specific dates in the middle.

e.g. on this picture  would like to disable date 18, 26, etc:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That is not a built in behavior - you would have to use a custom date picker.

Comment: Can you suggest one?

Comment: [This library](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) seems to have the ability to set only specific dates as acceptable.

Comment: Also this one can do this - https://github.com/square/android-times-square. Will try also the calendar you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I got a method by using custom datepicker. First we need to take the date as a string and then convert it into date object and then the date is converted to calendar object. At last by using setDisabledDays(calenderobj). We can disable it.
    The code is as follows.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                String a = "26-07-2017";
                java.util.Date date = null;
                try {
                    date = sdf.parse(a);
                    MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();
                    calendar = obj.dateToCalendar(date);
                    System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                List<Calendar> dates = new ArrayList<>();
                dates.add(calendar);
                Calendar[] disabledDays1 = dates.toArray(new Calendar[dates.size()]);
                dpd.setDisabledDays(disabledDays1);
                }


    private Calendar dateToCalendar(Date date) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        return calendar;
    }
```

Comment: May I know what does this dpd object?

Comment: dpd.setDisabledDays(disabledDays1);
In this line you are setting the disabledates to datepicker. that dpd is an object of custom datepicker

Comment: Their is no such function for datepicker as setDisabledDatys()

Comment: this code is for the [library](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) not for the default date picker