# Disable Sundays and any other Specific Date

Tags: java, android-datepicker

I want disable sundays and specific dates in particular months in android date picker

The Datepicker I used is android `datepicker`:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
calendar.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(27);
// calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
//calendar.set(2016,11,23);
// new   DatePickerDialog(LoginSuccess.this, listener, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(LoginSuccess.this, listener, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
// dpDialog.updateDate(2016,11,23);

DatePicker datePicker = dpDialog.getDatePicker();
//datePicker.updateDate(2016,11,23);
// Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
//dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newDate.getTime());
//datePicker.init();

if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)==Calendar.SUNDAY) {
   // dpDialog.setTitle("Sorry Sundays wont be accepted");
   // dpDialog.setMessage("not selected");
   // dpDialog.show();
    //datePicker.setBackgroundColor(000000);
    Color.parseColor("#000000");
}
else {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    datePicker.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    datePicker.setMinDate(now + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1));
    datePicker.setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    dpDialog.show();
}

public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

        //calendar.set(2016,11,23);
        display.setText("Selected Date:" + (dayOfMonth) + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
            Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
            ok.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginSuccess.this, Confirm.class);
                intent.putExtra("Date", dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                intent.putExtra("name", (String) spinnerOsversions.getSelectedItem());
                intent.putExtra("email4", email3.toString());
                intent.putExtra("bikeno4", bikeno3.toString());
                intent.putExtra("fname", fname.toString());
                //intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            });
    }
```

`SetMinDate` and `setMaxdate` is working Perfectly but I want to only disable sundays and particular days.

Comment: See if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727244/how-to-disable-certain-dates-in-the-android-date-picker-dialog/34730506#34730506 . It uses a custom date picker from - https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with the default DatePickerDialog. You might want to check out [MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker).

In `com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog` you have the method `public void setSelectableDays(Calendar[] selectableDays)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#additional-options

With the code below:
`datePicker.setSelectableDays(Calendar[] days)`

And put all available days into datePicker.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` for matching sunday 
use `DAY_OF_WEEK` which take values SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, and SATURDAY

```
if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK).equals(Calendar.SUNDAY)) {
   // dpDialog.setTitle("Sorry Sundays wont be accepted");
   // dpDialog.setMessage("not selected");
   // dpDialog.show();
    //datePicker.setBackgroundColor(000000);
    Color.parseColor("#000000");
}
```

Comment: This fixes that one if statement in OPs example code, but it doesn't actually disable Sundays in the datepicker/prevent users from selecting a sunday.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MaterialDatePicker` of https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android

```
val constraintsBuilder =
        CalendarConstraints.Builder().setValidator(DateValidatorWeekdays()).build()

    MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker().setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder).build()
        .show(childFragmentManager, "Data_Picker")
```

> DateValidator class:

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/datepicker/DateValidatorWeekdays.java